# How to make htaccess rule for a URL with specific characters?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to 301 redirect all `?print=yes` URLs to the URLs without `?print=yes` that contain the same name in them through `.htaccess`. Currently the button to `PRINT` is present in the header of the website so it's more than 70 URLs to fix... Removing the button to `PRINT` the page will ruin the design quite a bit, so it's not really an option.

I think it needs to be a `RedirectMatch` rule, but how do I write it?

**Example:** `redirect 301 from domain.com/faq/?print=yes to domain.com/faq`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sometimes I hate myself... It's not working because I wrote the wrong thing. It is `domain.com/faq/?print=yes` instead of `domain.com/faq?print=yes`. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^print=yes$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if redirect can do the same but here is how I would do it with rewrite

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?print=yes$ $1 [NC]
```

Comment: Techmonk, could you please edit your code accordingly? I am sorry for my non-existant syntax skills in this.

Comment: This will not work because RewriteRule cannot match query string.